# How to stop chrome from auto reloading tab when it stays open longer?

Tags: google-chrome

I've been using Window 7. It is just a bit annoying when tab is auto reloaded in Chrome browser when tab is kept open for longer. It always loses my data when page is auto reloaded.

Do you have any advise to stop this Chrome's behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same issue, when i keep any tab for long time like 3-4 minutes and when i go back it refresh it automatically.

Comment: That doesn't really appear to be a stack overflow question. Other than that, it's a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1048029

Answer (score 13):

Disable **Automatic tab discarding** at `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding`.

If enabled, tabs get automatically discarded from memory when the system memory is low. Discarded tabs are still visible on the tab strip and get reloaded when clicked on. Info about discarded tabs can be found at chrome://discards. #automatic-tab-discarding

Comment: More info here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/huyGBMWpM4w

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I have this setting set to Disabled, yet tabs that have been open a while are still reloading once I switch to them.

Comment: Having the same issue. Reset all flags to default, relaunched Chrome and reloaded tabs...worked for me!

Comment: Looks like now the options is `chrome://flags/#proactive-tab-freeze-and-discard`

Answer (score 6):

go to chrome://flags/ and set to "Disabled" flag "Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs" and hit Relaunch browser.

That's it

Answer (score 3):

you can disable this feature of chrome by going to this url :
*

> chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

*

Answer (score 1):

You can control the details of the new Chrome behaviour playing with the different options for the setting `#proactive-tab-freeze-and-discard`.

This allows more control than the `#automatic-tab-discarding` flag.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment the options is now called "Proactive tab freeze and discard" and can be found here:

```
chrome://flags/#proactive-tab-freeze-and-discard
```

The available values are:

```
Enabled
Enabled Freeze only
Enabled Freeze and discard
Enabled Freeze and discard, heuristics disabled
Disabled
```

I have seen this option in Chrome 75 and Brave 0.65 Chromium: 75.0